# PHP/MYSQL select records based on the timezone

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on timezone using php and mysql where I got a problem with selecting records based on timezone.I use the default timezone as America/Chicago and when I select records there I see that there is a difference in the records count based on the timezone.For example for a day if I see 250 records in UTC in EST I see 260 records.So how do I select the records according to the timezone?

Comment: What have you tried in your code?

Comment: By default MySQL uses UTC timezone. convert your local time to UTC before querying data from MySQL

Comment: Could probably get the time difference of a datetime and a unixtimestamp interpretation of that datetime (which is always UTC). That should give you the timezone offset.